# How can I setup my container Django app in Azure so it doesn't crash?

Tags: python, django, azure

Sometimes, my container Django app in Azure crashes.

The error I get is this:

> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. retried,
> and the latest reset reason: remote connection failure, transport
> failure reason: delayed connect error: 111

I haven't been able to figure out what's causing it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Description of issue is very common. 111 error typically points to issues with network connectivity or configuration within your Azure deployment. Use logging and remote debugging to get closer to the point of crash.

Answer (score 0):

The error could be due to the connection between the client and the server was closed before the server could send a response or misconfigured firewall (if any), a network issue, or issue with the server.

1. Check the firewall settings to ensure that the port used by the container app is open.
2. Check the network settings to ensure that there are no issues with the network.
3. Create and configure the container app in different region and try to deploy the Django application.
4. Make sure your application is up and running without any issues and is listening on the valid port and interface.
5. Run the application with Gunicorn command.
6. Expose the application to any other valid ports.
7. Navigate to Log Stream of your app in Azure, check the logs of the container app to see if there are any errors or issues that could be leading to the errors.

[image]

**Deployment Status:**

- Could deploy my Django application to Azure:

[image]

Comment: My app can run without issues for days, and it will just randomly crash. I see no explanation as to why I would get the error mentioned before:

upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. retried and the latest reset reason: remote connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111

I have attempted to implement health checks unsuccessfully.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the error you are getting could be due to *network issue or issues with the error or connection issues between the client and the server*.

Comment: So how can it be troubleshooted, @pravallika KV?

Comment: Did you try deploying the same application to a new app in different region?